# How to know that customer goes to checkout but doesn't complete checkout process?

Tags: checkout, cart, onestepcheckout, ecommerce-tracking

I want to put virtual pageview javascript in one step checkout but this javascript will only be fired if the customer does not complete the order.

So that i can see customers address info, shipping and payment method selection for failed payments.

Answer (score 1):

This is logically impossible. "Not completing the checkout" is nothing that happens but the absence of something happening.

#### What you can do instead (outlined):

1. trigger first script when user goes to checkout page
2. trigger second script when user completes checkout
3. list carts where (1) has been triggered but not (2) within a certain time

You don't need to do this in custom JavaScript. There are quite a few extensions that already handle it, like Ebizmarts Magemonkey. The keyword to look for is "Abandoned Cart".

Comment: Thanks @fschmengler . The keyword is very useful . Using abandoned cart we can check if the product is in cart for long time without order.

Comment: Not sure if I understand your concern. After "place order" click, the cart is not abandoned anymore.